# symfony2 jquery ui datepicker images

Tags: jquery-ui, symfony

I´m working with jQuery-ui datepicker but I have problems with images and paths. This is how I link my css:

```
    {% stylesheets  '@BackendBundle/Resources/public/css/bootstrap.min.css' 
                    '@BackendBundle/Resources/public/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css' 
                    '@HotelBundle/Resources/public/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.20.custom.css' 
                    '@HotelBundle/Resources/public/css/encargado.css'
               output='css/encargado.css' %}
        <link href="{{ asset_url }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    {% endstylesheets %}
{% endblock %}

{% block javascripts %}
    {% javascripts  '@BackendBundle/Resources/public/js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js' 
                    '@BackendBundle/Resources/public/js/modernizr-2.5.3-respond-1.1.0.min.js' 
                    '@HotelBundle/Resources/public/js/jquery-ui-1.8.20.custom.min.js' 
                    output='js/backend.js' %}
        <script src="{{ asset_url }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
    {% endjavascripts %}
```

and I save my files css files there:

```
../src/Gitek/HotelBundle/Resources/public/css/ui-lightness/
 - jquery-ui-1.8.20.custom.css
 - images/ui-bg_diagonals-thick_18_b81900_40x40.png;ui-bg_diagonals-thick_20_666666_40x40.png ...
```

my js files there:

```
../src/Gitek/HotelBundle/Resources/public/js/jquery-ui-1.8.20.custom.min.css
```

after that, I dump the assets with php app/console assetic:dump with no error

I also install the assets with php app/console assets:install web --symlink

and clear the cache php app/console cache:clear

I did all this and I can see and work with my datepicker, but some pictures are not loading. If I go to the Chrome console I can see these errors:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://hotel.local/app_dev.php/css/images/ui-bg_highlight-soft_100_eeeeee_1x100.png
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://hotel.local/app_dev.php/css/images/ui-bg_gloss-wave_35_f6a828_500x100.png
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://hotel.local/app_dev.php/css/images/ui-bg_glass_100_f6f6f6_1x400.png
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://hotel.local/app_dev.php/css/images/ui-icons_ffffff_256x240.png
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://hotel.local/app_dev.php/css/images/ui-bg_highlight-soft_75_ffe45c_1x100.png
```

I think that maybe the problem is with the paths within the css file but I´m not sure.

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to manually update path to images in the `jquery-ui-1.8.20.custom.min.css` file.

For [example](http://code.google.com/p/castle-age-auto-player/source/browse/trunk/jquery-ui-1.8.6/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.6.custom.css?r=80#61):

```
.ui-widget-content { border: 1px solid #dddddd; background: #eeeeee url(images/ui-bg_highlight-soft_100_eeeeee_1x100.png) 50% top repeat-x; color: #333333; }
```

You need to update `images/` by `/css/ui-lightness/images/`.

Comment: It works but I have to copy the ui-lightness folder to web/css/ folder manually. Thansks!

Comment: it is a bad idea to hack the lib, this will be broken the next time the lib is updated. The cssrewrite filter from the other answer is better.

Answer (score 1):

1) Enable the cssrewrite filter in config.yml:

```
assetic:
    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~
```

2) List the css files using relative URLs and the cssrewrite filter, e.g.

```
{% stylesheets '/bundles/backend/css/bootstrap.min.css' 
               '/bundles/backend/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css' 
               '/bundles/hotel/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.20.custom.css' 
               '/bundles/hotel/css/encargado.css'
               output='css/encargado.css' filter='cssrewrite' %}
<link href="{{ asset_url }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
{% endstylesheets %}
```

The filter should properly rewrite all CSS URLs.

Answer (score 0):

Do not modify external plugins.

Just override css like this:

```
.ui-state-default,
.ui-widget-content .ui-state-default,
.ui-widget-header .ui-state-default {
    background: #e6e6e6!important;
}

.ui-widget-header {
    background: #ccc!important;
}

.ui-state-hover,
.ui-widget-content .ui-state-hover,
.ui-widget-header .ui-state-hover,
.ui-state-focus,
.ui-widget-content .ui-state-focus,
.ui-widget-header .ui-state-focus {
    background: #dadada!important;
}

.ui-state-active,
.ui-widget-content .ui-state-active,
.ui-widget-header .ui-state-active,
.ui-widget-content {
    background: #fff!important;
}

.ui-state-highlight,
.ui-widget-content .ui-state-highlight,
.ui-widget-header .ui-state-highlight {
   background: #fbf9ee!important;
}

.ui-state-error,
.ui-widget-content .ui-state-error,
.ui-widget-header .ui-state-error {
    background: #fef1ec!important;
}
```

Add this css to your css file. It will remove this type of error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to load css using cssrewrite filter + load images.

```
{% block stylesheets %}
  {% stylesheets 'bundles/testbundle/css/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.css' filter='cssrewrite' %}
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" type="text/css" />
  {% endstylesheets %}
  {% image '@TestBundle/Resources/public/css/jquery-ui/images/*' %}{% endimage %}
{% endblock %}
```

Than install and dump the assets.